# Parallelogram geometry proof

Tags: geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A parallelogram and a line joining a vertex to the midpoint of opposite side](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9690/a-parallelogram-and-a-line-joining-a-vertex-to-the-midpoint-of-opposite-side)
>   [Proving two lines trisects a line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69655/proving-two-lines-trisects-a-line)

$\rm ABCD$ is a parallelogram (in the plane) and $\rm E$ is the midpoint of $\rm AB.$ Prove that $ \rm AC$ and $\rm DE$ trisect one another. In other words, that their point of intersection $\rm X$ divides
each of them in the ratio $2 : 1.$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Do the triangles $\bigtriangleup{AXE}$ and $\bigtriangleup{CXD}$ have anything in common?

Answer (score 0):

Medians of the triangle $ABD$ (see picture bellow) intersects in point $X$ and divide each other in ratio $2$:$1$ so we may write following:

$EX:DX=1:2$

$AX=\frac{2}{3}\frac{AC}{2}=\frac{AC}{3}  ,  XF=\frac{1}{3}\frac{AC}{2}=\frac{AC}{6}$

Since diagonals of the parallelogram divide each other in ratio $1:1$ we may write:

$XC=XF+\frac{AC}{2}=\frac{AC}{6}+\frac{AC}{2}=\frac{2AC}{3}$ , so we may conclude:

$AX:XC=\frac{AC}{3}:\frac{2AC}{3}=1:2$

[image]