# Prove using vectors line joining one of the vertices of a parallelogram to the midpoint of the opposite side intersects the diagonal in a ratio $1:2$.

Tags: geometry, vectors

Label the four vertices of a parallelogram in counterclockwise order as OPQR.
Prove that the line segment from $O$ to the midpoint of $PQ$ intersects the diagonal $PR$ in a
point $X$ that is $1/3$ of the way from $P$ to $R$.
I assumed $X$ is placed such that $\overrightarrow {PX}= a\ \overrightarrow {PR}$ and $\overrightarrow {XR}= b\ \overrightarrow {PR}$ but all I get after a bunch $f$ simplification is $a+b=1$
how do I proceed with this?

Comment: Hint: $\,X\,$ is the centroid of $\,\triangle OPQ\,$ (*why?*).

Comment: The conclusion is immediately obvious with similarity. You can just "convert" that solution by using the usual vector notation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parallelogram geometry proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73983/parallelogram-geometry-proof) - found through a link of [A parallelogram and a line joining a vertex to the midpoint of opposite side](/q/9690) in the RHS "Related" list, which the proposed duplicate was closed as being a duplicate of it. However, the other duplicate listed, i.e., [Proving two lines trisects a line](/q/69655), is more closely related to your problem.

Comment: thanks a lot, @dxiv